# SQL how to output a line with ONLY ONE "," and ONE character ";"

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

The query outputs lines with more than one comma, but I only need ONE comma and ONE semicolon

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE history_coord is NULL
   OR history_coord LIKE '%,%' AND history_coord LIKE '%;%'
```

How do I change the request? maybe I don't have to use "like"?

Comment: PostgreSQL used

Comment: Do you mean you don't want history_coords having two commas?

Comment: absolutely right

Comment: You could just exclude the rows with multiple commands for example: `history_coord NOT LIKE '%,%,%'`

Comment: Can you share sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward, just as you said - capture commas and semicolons with regular expressions using `regexp_matches` and then count them.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE history_coord IS NULL
   OR (select count(*) from regexp_matches(history_coord , ',', 'g')) = 1
  and (select count(*) from regexp_matches(history_coord , ';', 'g')) = 1;
```

**P.S.**
If your PostgreSQL version is 15+ then use function `regexp_count` which is roughly equivalent to the [scalar subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it by converting the string to an array using `string_to_array` and counts the length of the array using `array_length` and then substract 1 to count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string :

Simple data :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  history_coord varchar(50)
);

insert into mytable values
('one semicolon ;'),
('one comma ,'),
('one semicolon ; and one comma ,'),
('two semicolon ;; and one comma ,'),
('TEXT');
```

The query to get records with only one comma and one semi colon :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE array_length(string_to_array(history_coord, ','), 1) - 1 = 1
      and array_length(string_to_array(history_coord, ';'), 1) - 1 = 1
```

Result :

```
history_coord
one semicolon ; and one comma ,
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/r7orvoxr)